# How to pass arguments to custom Angular webpack build?

Tags: angular, webpack, build

I'm using Angular 7.2.1 and `@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser` for build of my application. 
I want to pass some arguments to the `webpack.config.js` file. When I am writing `ng serve` or `npm start` I'd like to add something like `--env=testing` parameter and then have this value available in my `webpack.config.js`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be simply passed this way:

```
ENV=testing npm run build
```